# Playing background music during entire game

Tags: android

I am developing a memory game, in which I want to play background music while starting the game.

I used sound pool class and successfully executed it, but I have problem in playing. I added `.mp3` audio file of two minutes, but it's playing only for 15 seconds more.

Can anyone say what problem I have? This is my soundclass file:

```
public class Soundclass {
    private SoundPool soundpool;
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundpoolmap;
    private AudioManager audiomanager;
    private Context context;

    public void initSounds(Context thecontext) {
        context = thecontext;
        soundpool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
        soundpoolmap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        audiomanager = (AudioManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }

    public Soundclass() {

    }

    public void addSound(int Index, int soundID) {
        soundpoolmap.put(Index, soundpool.load(context, soundID, 1));
    }

    public void playSound(int Index) {
        float streamVolume = audiomanager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        streamVolume = streamVolume
                / audiomanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        soundpool.play(soundpoolmap.get(Index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1,
                0, 1f);
    }

    public void playLoopedSound(int Index) {
        float streamVolume = audiomanager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        streamVolume = streamVolume
                / audiomanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        soundpool.play(soundpoolmap.get(Index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1,
                -1, 1f);
    }

}
```

and i used this class for given activitycalss .in oncreate function

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sound);
        soundclass = new Soundclass();

        soundclass.initSounds(getBaseContext());
        soundclass.addSound(1, R.raw.jinglebells);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                soundclass.playSound(1);

            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean "2 to develop a memory game"? Why did you use the prefix 2?

Comment: @Lion see now (I done my best to make the question readable)

Comment: @mH16 see now (I done my best to make the question readable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Soundpool is not meant to be used for background music. It has many limitations such as file size loading and playing time. It's mainly used for sound effects.
Use the MediaPlayer class for background music.

Comment: thanks for ur guide. i ll try in mediapalyer to play this file

Comment: hey i used meadiaplayer for background music..it getting execute thanks.